# Metric equivalence distance

Tags: general-topology, analysis

i have $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d'(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0, ~\text{in}~ x=y\\ |x|+|y|,~\text{if}~ x\neq y\end{cases}$

is this two distances are metric equivalent ?

We say that that two distances $d,d'$ are metric equivalent iff $$\exists \alpha,\beta>0,\forall x,y\in E , \alpha d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)\leq \beta d(x,y)$$

we have that for $\alpha=1, d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)$ what about the other inequality ?

thank you

Comment: Given $x \neq y$, isn't it enough to take $\beta = \frac{|x|+|y|}{|x-y|}$?

Comment: i don't know, i just prove that they are not topologicaly equivalent so the must be not metric equivalent , so i don't know

Comment: Are you sure the definition is correct? It seems to me the quantifiers are swapped... In that case, I'd say they're not equivalent

Comment: @amrsa you are right ; $\exists \alpha,\beta, \forall x,y  $

Comment: Then I believe these are known as [strongly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence).

Answer (score 0):

If there is $\beta > 0$ such that 
$$|x| + |y| \leq \beta |x - y|,$$
for all $x \neq y$,
then, fix $\beta$ and let $x = \beta$ and $y = \beta + 1$.
It follows that $2\beta + 1 \leq \beta \cdot 1$, a contradiction.